# Chaining methods and changing order of execution

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
    public class A
    {
    private List<Action> operations = new List<Action>();
    public A Method1()
    {
        //some code here
        operations.Add(DoStuff1);
        //some more code here
        return this;
    }

    public A Method2()
    {
        //some code here
        operations.Add(DoStuff2);
        //some more code here
        return this;
    }

    public A Method3()
    {
        //some code here
        operations.Add(DoStuff3);
        //some more code here
        return this;
    }

    private void DoStuff1() { }
    private void DoStuff2() { }
    private void DoStuff3() { }
}

a.Method1().Method2().Method3();
```

How do I trigger the execution of all operations in operations list, from within Method1()? I cant check the list against a fixed size, since there can be any number in the list? The only thing certain is that DoStuff1 will be there.

The chaining order should be the same, so I can't call a.Method3().Method2().Method1()

Basically I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Sequence mySequence = DOTween.Sequence();
mySequence.Append(transform.DOMoveX(45, 1))
.Append(transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0,180,0), 1))
.PrependInterval(1)
.Insert(0, transform.DOScale(new Vector3(3,3,3), mySequence.Duration()));
```

like here: http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type does not need to know/guess that. Add Action instances to the list for each relevant call. Have your class/type expose a method called `Execute` (*pick an appropriate name*). That call goes through the list of actions (*in reverse order in this case*) and executes them. The caller is responsible for calling that method just like the caller is responsible for calling the other methods to begin with.

```
public class A
{
    private List<Action> operations = new List<Action>();
    public A Method1()
    {
        operations.Add(DoStuff1);
        return this;
    }

    public A Method2()
    {
        operations.Add(DoStuff2);
        return this;
    }

    public A Method3()
    {
        operations.Add(DoStuff3);
        return this;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        operations.Reverse();
        foreach(var operation in operations)
           operation();
        operations.Clear();
    }

    private void DoStuff1() { }
    private void DoStuff2() { }
    private void DoStuff3() { }
}
```

#### Caller

```
a.Method1().Method2().Method3().Execute();
```

Or

```
a = a.Method1().Method2().Method3();
a.Execute();
```

Or

```
a.Method1();
a.Method2();
a.Method3();
a.Execute();
```

etc.